# Is continuous extension on dense subset an isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

If we have that $X \subset V$ is dense linear subspace. Where $V$ is normed space. I can show that for any $f \in X^{*}$, there exists a unique extension $\bar{f}$. I want to know if it can be shown that the mapping $\phi(f) = \bar{f}$ is an isometry?

My idea is to use the following two results. The first is a Corollary of the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

**Corollary**:
Let $X \subset V$ be a linear subspace. If $f \in X^{*}$ then there exists $\bar{f} \in V^{*}$ that extends $f$ such that $$\Vert \bar{f} \Vert_{V^{*}} = \Vert f \Vert_{X^{*}}$$

and the

**Theorem**:
Let $X$ be a subspace of some metric space $(V, \rho_{1})$ and $(Y,\rho_{2})$ a complete metric space. Then, if $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is uniformly continuous there exists a unique extension $\bar{f}: \bar{X} \rightarrow Y$ which is uniformly continuous.

Together I think this gives the result I'm looking for.

Comment: You don't even need Hahn-Banach. The (uniform) continuity gives the _unique_ continuous extension $\overline{f}$ of $f$ to $V$. Clearly $$\lVert \overline{f}\rVert = \sup \{ \lvert \overline{f}(v)\rvert : v\in V, \lVert v\rVert \leqslant 1\} \geqslant \lVert f\rVert = \sup \{\lvert f(x)\rvert : x\in X, \lVert x\rVert \leqslant 1\},$$ and by the denseness of $X$, the converse inequality.

Comment: @DanielFischer Without telling me how to use the density, could I ask if the idea is to show that $\{|\bar{f}(v)|:v \in V, \Vert v \Vert \leq 1 \} \subset \{|f(x)|:x \in X, \Vert x \Vert \leq 1 \}$?

Comment: Did you mean $\{ \lvert \overline{f}(v)\rvert : v \in V, \lVert v\rVert \leqslant 1\} \subset \overline{\{\lvert f(x)\rvert : x\in X, \lVert x\rVert \leqslant 1\}}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer No I didn't, but now I think I should have...

Comment: Indeed you should have. It can happen that the supremum is attained in $V$ but not in $X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't really follow why you are stating "It can happen that the supremum is attained in $V$ but not in $X$"? Could I ask without telling me the answer if I am on the right track in stating that for a convergent sequence $x_{n} \rightarrow x$ the supremum of $\sup\limits\{|x_{n}|:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is the same as the supremum of $\sup\limits\{\{{|x_{n}|: n \in \mathbb{N}}\} \cup \{{x}\}\}$. Am I on to something or way off?

Comment: Yes, the suprema are equal. It can happen that there is a $v\in V$ with $\lVert v\rVert = 1$ and $\lvert \overline{f}(v)\rvert = \lVert f\rVert$, but for all $x\in X$ with $\lVert x\rVert = 1$ we have $\lvert f(x)\rvert < \lVert f\rVert$. That is, the supremum - $\lVert f\rVert$ - is attained in $V$, but not in $X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh yes I understand that, I was asking what I said that caused you to write the statement. DO you think I could use this idea of the sequences to prove the reverse inequality $\Vert \bar{f} \Vert \leq \Vert f \Vert$?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. It all boils down to show that $\{ x\in X : \lVert x\rVert \leqslant 1\}$ is dense in $\{ v\in V : \lVert v\rVert \leqslant 1\}$, whichever way you go about it.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm trying to practice proofs, so let me know if this fine if you have time, it might not be the most elegant. I want to to prove that it is dense. The first inclusion $\overline{\{x \in X: \Vert x \Vert \leq 1\}} \subset \{ v \in V: \Vert v \Vert \leq 1 \}$ is trivial. Take $v_{1} \in  \{ v \in V: \Vert v \Vert \leq 1 \}$. We know that $B(v_{1},\epsilon) \cap X \neq \emptyset$. Not yet done will continue now...

Comment: `\overline{xyz}`, not `\bar`. Hint: Show first that $\{ x : \lVert x\rVert < 1\}$ is dense in $\{ v : \lVert v\rVert < 1\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is there something that doesn't follow with my proof?

Comment: You cannot get $x$ independent of $\epsilon$. For every $n$, you have an $x_n$ such that ...

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay but then the proof still works for some $x_{n}$? Since using what I did you can show that each $x_{n} \in X$.

Comment: Therefore there exists an $x_{n} \in X$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\Vert x_{n} \Vert - \Vert v_{1} \Vert \leq \Vert v_{1} - x_{n} \Vert < \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. Therefore either $\Vert x_{n} \Vert \leq 1$ and we are done or we have that $1 < \Vert x_{n} \Vert < 1 + \frac{1}{n}$. Then it follows that $\frac{x_{n}}{M} \in B(v,\epsilon) \cap \{x \in X: \Vert x \Vert \leq 1 \}$ where $M \geq 2$. $\therefore \{ v \in V: \Vert v \Vert \leq 1 \} \subset \overline{\{ x \in X: \Vert x \Vert \leq 1\}}$.

Comment: If $1 < \lVert x\rVert < 1 + \frac{1}{n}$, why would $\frac{x}{M}$ be close to $v_1$ if $M \geqslant 2$? You could take $\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot x$, that has norm $\leqslant 1$ and is close to $x$, so it's still not far away from $v_1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay but is $\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot x_{n}$ still guaranteed to be in $B(v_{1},\epsilon)$? By the way thanks for all the discussion.

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed to be in $B(v_1,\epsilon)$. But  it's guaranteed to be in $B(v_1,2\epsilon)$. If you take the open ball first, you avoid that (small, very small) difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

This was sorted out in comments, so I'll add a slightly different point of view. Every bounded linear  operator $T:X\to V$ has the *adjoint* operator $T^*:V^*\to X^*$ defined by $T^*(f)=f\circ T$. The definition shows that $\|T^*\|\le \|T\|$. (In fact, equality holds by Hahn-Banach, but we do not need this here).

In the special case when $T$ is an isometric embedding with dense image, the operator $T^*$ is surjective, because every  $f\in X^*$ extends to an element $\bar f\in V^*$ via $\bar f(x) = \lim_{y\to x} f(y)$. Also,  since 
$$|\bar f(x)|\le \lim_{y\to x}\|f\|\, \|y\| = \|f\|\,\|x\|$$
we have $\|\bar f\|\le \|f\|$. Hence, $T^*$ is a surjective isometry in this case.